# Saying "I ran home" correct?

Tags: conjugations

> 私は家に走りました

Is the る conjugated to become り?

Comment: What's exactly the problem in "る conjugated to become り"? I mean, what would you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 走る is a godan verb, meaning that it conjugates like this:

走ります
走って
走れる
走らせる
走られる
etc.

As compared to an ichidan verb like 食べる, where all its conjugates just add something to the 食べ stem (食べます, 食べて, etc.).